# How to get column data to a variable

Tags: php, mysql, session

I need to lookup how much points someone has that is presently logged in.

So I have a column name being userId when someone is logged in. I've got this php script to lookup which userId somebody has.

```
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';

 // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
 if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) { 
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit;
 }
 // select loggedin users detail
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
 $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$userId=$_SESSION['user'];
```

But in the table every user has points. How to look up how much points a user has?

Comment: is this exact code?

Comment: Food for thought: Please don't use `<br>`'s in code to put them on new lines. Use the code editor's indenting method. That's what it's there for.

Comment: If your session array is a string, then your query is failing. We also don't know which API you're using to connect with and if the session array does contain a value. Check for errors via both PHP and MySQL.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: Hint: It's in `$userRow`.

Comment: But then I get `Array`

Comment: @AaronJonk Yes. `$userRow` is an array. Use `var_dump($userRow)` and you'll see where the value you want is. To get the specific value, just access the appropriate array key `$userRow['points']` (or whatever the points key is called).